# How to initialize static blocks?

Tags: java, static

I have to work with a bunch of static legacy classes that contain `static` blocks.
The classes itself are only helper classes with only static methods.

Example:

```
public abstract class Legacy {
    protected static final String[] ARRAY;

    static {
        //init that ARRAY
    }

    public static String convert(String value) {
        //makes use of the ARRAY variable
    }
}
```

Important: I don't have control over the sources and thus cannot modify the code. I know that this is a serious design flaw in how the class is build.

Problem: when accessing the class concurrently, I get exceptions from the legacy classes if the class is not initialized yet. So I have to ensure at application startup that each static class was initialized properly before.

But how could I do this?

I tried as follows:

```
Legacy.class.newInstance();
```

But that results in the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
```

So probably I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: The static method and fields of a class are first initialized by the java class loader, when the class is first time referenced in the code.

Comment: Well, since this is just a bypass of another problem, we should focus on the main problem, don't you think? What is the exception you've mentioned? ("I get exceptions if the class is not initialized yet")

Comment: Static initializers will already only run once, in a single thread... perhaps you could give us some examples of what you're talking about. Trying to construct an *instance* of a class with no accessible constructors isn't a good idea.

Comment: In order to static load the class, you can just have a reference to the class itself with ClassName.class; For example, Class<?> = ClassName.class. This will only initialize the static fields on that class.

Comment: The exception you are getting has a cause. You need to log that as well.

Comment: @RaviWallau No, that won't initialize the class, it will just give you the entry point to reflecting over it. You need to access an actual member of the class.

Comment: Please see my update of an example class. As written, I cannot modify the sourcecode, but have to find a way to ensure initialization on startup.

Comment: @membersound why do you believe the error is due to incomplete initialization rather than simple concurrent access? Can you give an example of what happens in convert & the stack trace for the error you see?

Comment: @henry great that works. Would you add this as an answer as this is probably the right answer to the initial question?

Comment: @membersound I take it you found that "convert" modifies the array?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik,  agreed,  I just tested this and loading the class is not enough.  You have to actually use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static initializers are thread safe in that they will only be run, and by a single thread.

They may run multiple times if the class is loaded by more than one classloader, but in that case they are effectively initializing a different class.

It is therefore unlikely that the problem you are seeing is due to incomplete initialization.

It seems more likely that your `convert` method is doing something that is not thread safe such as modifying the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you call only static methods of the legacy classes there is no need to create an instance. The static block will be executed only once (the JVM will take care of it).

See this small example.

```
class Legacy {
    static {
        System.out.println("static initializer of Legacy");
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Legacy.doSomething()");
    }
}

class LegacyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Legacy.doSomething();
    }
}
```

If you run LegacyDemo it will print

```
static initializer of Legacy
Legacy.doSomething()
```